# Solve Ax = b (A and b both large and very sparse), but only for the values in some rows of x

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I have a linear system $Ax=b$ where:

- $A$ is square, large ($m$ and $n$ on the order of $10^5$), asymmetric, very sparse (around $0.05\%$ non-zeros)
- $b$ is very sparse (also $0.05\% - 0.1\%$ non-zeros)

Due to the properties of the problem where the matrix $A$ and vector $b$ come from, I can guarantee the system has one unique solution $x$.

Currently, I'm solving this system using sparse LU decomposition or BiCGSTAB and this is already quite fast. But in the search for more speed, which is my primary goal, I realised that, given how the vector $x$ is used once calculated, I only actually look at a very small subset of its values. In other words, if $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & \cdots & x_n \end{bmatrix}^T$, then I actually only need to know the values of a few $x_i$ (few is about $0.1\%$). I know which values $x_i$ I care about before solving $Ax = b$. After solving the system, all other values in $x$ can be completely incorrect or zero so long as those important $x_i$ are right.

Is there any faster algorithm that can take advantage of this to reduce the amount of work done when solving $Ax=b$?

Note: An obvious general way to calculate $x_i$ values directly is using Cramer's rule but I don't know how it could be applied to such large sparse matrices quickly.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I haven't heard of such an algorithm.

Comment: Assuming $x$ is a column vector. Let $B$ be the matrix you get after throwing away all other rows except for those i'th rows. Do the same with $b$, to get $c$. Then we have $Bx=c$. This will be a smaller system to solve.

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli why would I throw away rows from $A$ if it's the rows of $x$ that I don't care about, not the rows from $b$?

Comment: Well, because i'th row of A times (whole of) x gives the i'th row of b. But actually the thing I said will not work: you may lose uniqueness of solutions. You may get new x's that are different from the unique one we originally had -- including in the rows of interest :( My bad. I will think more...

Comment: Have you used tic-toc function to measure the time taken (minutes, hours?) Can you provide a sample .mat file if you could so I could help you @Alex

Comment: Also is $A$ fixed? are you solving for multiple right hand sides?

Comment: @BEIRUT I’m actually not using MATLAB, I’m using C++ and the Eigen library but I guess given that the algorithm is the point here it’s probably not very relevant. It’s on the order of tens of milliseconds for smaller matrices (about 5000*5000). Unfortunately I can’t provide you with code... but apart from the code for building $A$ and $b$, the solving code super standard Eigen stuff.

Comment: @BEIRUT one matrix $A$ for one vector $b$

Comment: I will provide a feasible answer in a moment